# Dockerfile and yml configuration

Tags: php, docker

I use docker (with nginx - docker-nginx-php-mysql) as the environment to run PHP applications.
I'm trying to add websocket to my application and have some difficulties in configure to Dockerfileand docker-compose.yml

I have server file in cmd.php (location: docker-nginx-php-mysql\www\ratchet_chatapp\cmd.php):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use ChatApp\Chat;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8090
);

$server->run();
```

I use the connection to open the web socket on main.js (location: docker-nginx-php-mysql\www\ratchet_chatapp\js\main.js) with:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8090');
    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };
```

my Dockerfile (location: docker-nginx-php-mysql\php\Dockerfile):

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzip-dev libpng-dev git zip unzip libgd3 libgd-tools  libxml2 libxml2-dev mariadb-client && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql  mysqli gd soap zip
```

my docker-compose.yml (location: docker-nginx-php-mysql):

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html 
    networks:
        uln:
         ipv4_address: 10.6.0.2

  php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
        - 8090
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html 
    networks:
        uln:
         ipv4_address: 10.6.0.3

  app:
    image: php:7.3-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    volumes:
        - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: webprog 
        MYSQL_USER: webprog 
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: webprog
    networks:
        uln:
         ipv4_address: 10.6.0.4

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
    networks:
        uln:
         ipv4_address: 10.6.0.5

networks:
    uln:
     ipam:
        config:
         - subnet: 10.6.0.0/16
```

I tried to configure the Dockerfile with EXPOSE 8090 and add it to the yml but still doesn't work.
How can I change the Dockerfile and the yml properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ori, your connection should be pointing to your container address, right?

Comment: Yes. how can I find the container address?

Comment: It's the IP address that you have assigned on your yml, or, you can execute _docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash_ to enter in your container and find it's IP.

Comment: You can't reach anything you don't publish with the `ports:` setting; also remember that Javascript generally runs on a host browser and can't access the Docker networking.  The container-internal IP addresses are unusable except on one specific Docker configuration and I'd completely ignore them (delete them from the `docker-compose.yml` file and never look them up).

Answer (score 0):

Your container 8090 port is mapped to your 9000 port on localhost, so you should try pointing to localhost:9000 to reach the container's websocket port i.e. ws://localhost:9000